# How to select from postgresql table that return distinct values of particular columns with PK field

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct

take example of below table where ID is PrimaryKey

| ID | user | organization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | xyz |
| 2 | def | uvw |
| 3 | abc | xyz |
| 4 | def | xyz |
| 5 | def | uvw |

I want to select from this table with DISTINCT values of user and organization along with the ID. So what I'm expecting is a result like one of the below. ie; either this

| ID | user | organization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | xyz |
| 2 | def | uvw |
| 4 | def | xyz |

or this

| ID | user | organization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | abc | xyz |
| 5 | def | uvw |
| 4 | def | xyz |

How do I write a query for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE temp TABLE test (
    ID int,
    _user text,
    _organization text
);

SELECT DISTINCT ON (_user, _organization)
    id,
    _user,
    _organization
FROM
    test
ORDER BY
    _user,
    _organization,
    id;
```

--desc

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (_user, _organization)
        id,
        _user,
        _organization
    FROM
        test
    ORDER BY
        _user,
        _organization,
        id DESC;
```

useful link: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
select max(id), max(users), max(org) from tbl1 group by users,org;
```

or this

```
select min(id), min(users), min(org) from tbl1 group by users,org;
```